# input text box to display ending portion than from start

Tags: html, css, angular

Need help displaying tail end portion of the entered text rather than start of the text inside an input text field.

Sample string entered could be "Starting portion, Ending Portion". Depending on the length of the input field(assuming length is set to 14 chars), instead of displaying first 14 characters in the visible area of text input, it should display last 14 characters of the string -> " Ending Portion"

Thanks in advance
ASJ

Comment: provide more information with an example

Comment: Sample string entered could be "Starting portion, Ending Portion". Depending on the length of the input field(assuming length is set to 14 chars), instead of displaying first 14 characters in the visible area of text input,  it should display last 14 characters of the string -> " Ending Portion"

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the following code

```js
var el = document.getElementById('textField');
el.focus();
el.scrollLeft = el.scrollWidth;
```

```html
<input id="textField" value = "Starting portion, Ending Portion">
```

Comment: `el.focus()` is not necessary.

Comment: Wrap the JS code example into `window.onload = () => { ... }` to make it work.